# Excessive lstlisting whitespace when using escape

Tags: white-space

I am trying to remove the excessive whitespace between the bullet points and the second hi.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{hitec}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)} 
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{page}
\begin{document}
hi %normal
\begin{lstlisting}
text
\end{lstlisting}
hi % problem, large white space 
\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols} @*)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the exsessive whitespace between the bullet points and hi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This vertical white space is explained by 3 elements:

1. Space added above the `lstlisting` environment. You can remove it by setting the `aboveskip` option to `0pt`.
2. Apparently, escaped TeX code inside `lstlisting` starts in horizontal mode, and `multicols`' behavior when called in horizontal mode is to start on a new line. You can trick it by either adding `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` before calling `multicols`, or putting the whole environment inside a `\vbox{}`.
3. `multicols` also adds vertical space above its content. You can remove it by specifying locally `\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}`, as answered in [Reduce vertical spacing itemize and multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51312/reduce-vertical-spacing-itemize-and-multicols).

You may remove all of it:

[image: Source and all-removed]

but what's really "excessive" depends on the results you're looking for.
Whitespace number 2 is probably unwanted. If you want the same vertical space as between regular text and `multicols`, remove 1 and 2:

[image: Removed 1 and 2]

If you want the same vertical space as between regular text and `lstlisting`'s text (like the beginning of your example), remove 2 and 3:

[image: Removed 2 and 3]

Here is the full working code for these examples:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{hitec}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)} 
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{page}
\begin{document}

\noindent Source
\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}@*)
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent Removing all white space
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt]
(*@\vbox{\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}}@*)
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent Removing 1 and 2 % as if the text was directly followed by multicols
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt]
(*@\vbox{\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}}@*)
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent Removing 2 and 3 % same space as if it was only text
\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\vbox{\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}}@*)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```